# JAVA 8: how to pass -xms and -xmx JVM values in the command

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, jvm-arguments

I'm running a **springboot** app on **Java 8** environment

The command I use to run my app is this:

```
spring-boot:run -Plocalmysql -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dspring.profiles.active=localmysql
```

My purpose is to add JVM values specification to my command; so i was suggested to use this options syntax: 
`"-Drun.jvmArguments=Xms512m -Xmx512m"`

But while running it throws me this warning :

```
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
> PermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Is there any workaround or a solution to keep passing it in the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a warning message about another JVM parameter `-XX:PermSize` which is not supported since Java 8, because Permanent Generation was [replaced with Metaspace](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace).

If you're having issues with setting JVM options for the memory size, for Spring Boot 2 you should use `spring-boot.run.jvmArguments` parameter:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Plocalmysql -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dspring.profiles.active=localmysql -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
```

Or you can set these parameters in the Maven plugin configuration part of `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>
            -Xms512m
            -Xmx1024m
        </jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: so you think that my command goes welle and it adjust the memory values like i want it to do ?

Comment: Yes, the warning message may be ignored, possibly some of your tools is configured to set this JVM parameter.  And setting of memory sizes is not disabled :)